# Default Website Page error - While installing wordpress multisites on a subdomain

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress multisites in my directory, everything is working perfectly except the fact that the main page of the sister sites shows "Default Website Page" error and redirects me to "http://geek.thelazy.info/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi".

The error occurs only when I open geek.thelazy.info and at specific places (not on places far from here), and only when I open the main page. At all other pages say like geek.thelazy.info/devashish site works regardless of anything.

Any clues on how to solve this problem?

Comment: See http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/domain-redirecting-cgi-sys-defaultwebpage-cgi-139597-p5.html#post868632 (and rest of that thread) for a potential solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is to wait for a day or two. This helped me. But, I am not sure what if there is any other workaround at the server side as well because it is not really trivial to put a live site down for 1-2 days.